# Hide default action (=Index) from url on ASP.NET Core 3.1 application

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm looking for a solution to hide the default action name from url in a ASP.NET Core 3.1 application. The default action is in all controllers named Index and since migration of ASP.NET MCV 4 to ASP.NET Core 3.1 is the name Index displayed in url and configured in links.

What I did:
Startup.cs

```html
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public  static IServiceCollection CmsServices { get; set; }      

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            CmsServices = services;
            services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
            {
                options.EnableForHttps = true;
            });


            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                });

            services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
            {
                //options.BufferBody = true;
                options.KeyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
                options.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
                options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                options.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews(
                options =>
                    {
                        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
                        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                    }).AddNewtonsoftJson(
                x =>
                    {
                        x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    })
                .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddLogging();
            services.AddCmsConfigurations();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(
                options =>
                    {
                        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
                    });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseResponseCompression();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

For menu in _Layout.cshtml

```html
<a class="fa fa-home" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
<a class="fa fa-home" asp-area="" asp-controller="Company" asp-action="Index">Companies</a>
```

The url of root domain (=HomeController - Action=Index) is like expected. Just the domain without controller and action name.
The url for CompanyController action Index is company/index instead just company.

I tried following, but without success.

```html
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("company", 
                    "{controller=Company}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Index" });

                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

I can not find a solution. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, maybe comes this issue from another route config with the RouteAttribute.

We had on our BaseController the attribute `[Route("[controller]/[action]")]`. After replacing of action pattern to `[Route("[controller]/{action=Index}")]`, is the name index no longer visible in url.